# javascript/mongoose can not add a key/value pair to an object?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I use mongoose to return a data named doc, then I want to add a key/value pair to that doc but not work, the code is like:

```
 Account.findOne({_id:accountId},function(err,doc){
      if (doc != null) {
               var obj = {};
               obj = doc;
               obj["key"] = value;// not work
      }
})
```

I simplified my code above. I have to first new an obj and then let obj = doc, then add key/value.

I find some information about "use restrict" but I do not write it in mongoose and I do not know how to do with it.

Comment: thats mongoose document object, not normal object, you need to call, toObject or call query with .lean()

Comment: Sorry I do not really understand, do you mean doc.toObject()? I try this doc.toObject();  obj = doc; obj["key"] = value; still not work

Comment: also i use typeof to see the type of doc, it print "object". I guess javascript typeof can not tell mongoose obj or normal obj

Comment: var obj = doc.toObject()

Comment: all objects returns object, you need toString() or try instanceOf to properly check

Comment: var obj = doc.toObject() not work, I can not add key/value to obj - - I use doc.toString and print it, it looks like normal object

Comment: try `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(doc));` and see it is normal object or not.

Comment: console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(doc)); print:[object Object]. I use a new obj to move all doc's key value into it. Just a temporary solution.